# pandas dataframe in a long format missing months

Tags: python, pandas, date

I can't find a way to add the month in a long format dataframe.
For example for each country, and each year I would like to have 12 values, once by month.
And the value of total_points (which will be NaN) will be the same as the last one.
It means that my column month should be range(1,13) for each country and each year.

```
country_full    year    month        rank   rank_date   total_points    
Zimbabwe       2021        8         108    2021-08-12  1171.88
Zimbabwe       2021        10        108    2021-09-12  1171.88
Zimbabwe       2022        01        108    2022-01-12  1171.88
Germany        1994        01        10     1994-01-10  1171.88
Germany        1994        02        10     1994-02-09  1327.8
Germany        1994        04        10     1994-04-07  1459.9
```

The desired output would be :

```
country_full    year    month        rank   rank_date   total_points    
    Zimbabwe       2021        8         108    2021-08-12  1171.88
    Zimbabwe       2021        9         108    2021-08-12  1171.88
    Zimbabwe       2021        10        108    2021-10-12  1171.88
    Zimbabwe       2021        11        108    2021-11-12  1171.88
    Zimbabwe       2021        12        108    2021-12-12  1171.88
    Zimbabwe       2022        01        108    2022-01-12  1171.88
    Germany        1994        01        10     1994-01-10  1171.88
    Germany        1994        02        10     1994-02-10  1327.8
    Germany        1994        03        10     1994-03-09  1459.9
    Germany        1994        04        10     1994-03-07  1459.9
```

For each country and each year having 12 months. And the missing values for the total point column will be the one from the last month.

Any idea of how we can do that with pandas ?

Comment: could you please add a desired output for the given example?

Comment: I updated my answer. Have a look if that works for you. I couldn't find any mistakes but I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that all `rank_date` are on the day `12`, you can use `reindex` with `MS` frequency and then use `pd.offsets` to add days:

```
new_indexes = ( pd.date_range(start=f"{df['year'].min()}", 
  end=f"{df['year'].max() + 1}", freq='MS', inclusive='left') + pd.offsets.Day(11) )

# forward and backward fills and reindexing the columns to the actual format
new_df = ( df.set_index('rank_date').reindex(new_indexes).ffill().bfill().
      reset_index().rename({'index':'rank_date'}, axis=1).reindex(df.columns, axis=1) )

# we need to update year and month columns                                                                                                                           
new_df['year'] = new_df['rank_date'].dt.year
new_df['month'] = new_df['rank_date'].dt.month
```

Output:

```
country_full    year    month   rank    rank_date   total_points
0   Zimbabwe    2021    1   108.0   2021-01-12  1171.88
1   Zimbabwe    2021    2   108.0   2021-02-12  1171.88
2   Zimbabwe    2021    3   108.0   2021-03-12  1171.88
3   Zimbabwe    2021    4   108.0   2021-04-12  1171.88
4   Zimbabwe    2021    5   108.0   2021-05-12  1171.88
5   Zimbabwe    2021    6   108.0   2021-06-12  1171.88
6   Zimbabwe    2021    7   108.0   2021-07-12  1171.88
7   Zimbabwe    2021    8   108.0   2021-08-12  1171.88
8   Zimbabwe    2021    9   108.0   2021-09-12  1171.88
9   Zimbabwe    2021    10  108.0   2021-10-12  1171.88
10  Zimbabwe    2021    11  108.0   2021-11-12  1171.88
11  Zimbabwe    2021    12  108.0   2021-12-12  1171.88
12  Zimbabwe    2022    1   108.0   2022-01-12  1171.88
13  Zimbabwe    2022    2   108.0   2022-02-12  1171.88
14  Zimbabwe    2022    3   108.0   2022-03-12  1171.88
15  Zimbabwe    2022    4   108.0   2022-04-12  1171.88
16  Zimbabwe    2022    5   108.0   2022-05-12  1171.88
17  Zimbabwe    2022    6   108.0   2022-06-12  1171.88
18  Zimbabwe    2022    7   108.0   2022-07-12  1171.88
19  Zimbabwe    2022    8   108.0   2022-08-12  1171.88
20  Zimbabwe    2022    9   108.0   2022-09-12  1171.88
21  Zimbabwe    2022    10  108.0   2022-10-12  1171.88
22  Zimbabwe    2022    11  108.0   2022-11-12  1171.88
23  Zimbabwe    2022    12  108.0   2022-12-12  1171.88
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer that did almost the job :) In fact, I have an error : "cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels", because, I think, I need to do dit for each country. I edited the question to be more clear.

Comment: so your output has to be monthly data from 1994 till 2022 for germany and also from 1994 till 2022 for zimbabwe?

Comment: Yes for every country (almost 100), and every year (it starts really in 1900).  And whatever the day, but I need one row for each month/by year/by country.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I would do it. As far as I can see it produces the desired output. (Used Input at the bottom of the answer).

Create the new time index with `MS` (see documentation with the [`Offset aliases`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html#offset-aliases) and combine it to a Multiindex with the country.
(credits to @Nuri Taş on how to define start and end of the `date_range`, I just copied that part)

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df[['year', 'month']].assign(day=1))
t_index = pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.date_range(start=f"{df['year'].min()}", end=f"{df['year'].max() + 1}", freq="MS"))

new_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([t_index, df['country_full'].unique()])
```

Set the relevant columns as index and reindex with the new created Multiindex, sort the data, groupby the country to use `ffill` and `bfill`

```
df = df.set_index(['date', 'country_full'])

out = (
    df
    .reindex(new_index)
    .sort_index(level=1)
    .groupby(level=1)
    .ffill()
    .bfill()
)

out['year'] = out.index.get_level_values(0).year
out['month'] = out.index.get_level_values(0).month
```

Output:

```
                     year  month   rank   rank_date  total_points
2020-01-01 Germany   2020      1   10.0  1994-01-12       1171.88
2020-02-01 Germany   2020      2   10.0  1994-02-12       1327.80
2020-03-01 Germany   2020      3   10.0  1994-02-12       1327.80
2020-04-01 Germany   2020      4   10.0  1994-04-12       1459.90
2020-05-01 Germany   2020      5   10.0  1994-04-12       1459.90
2020-06-01 Germany   2020      6   10.0  1994-04-12       1459.90
2020-07-01 Germany   2020      7   10.0  1994-04-12       1459.90
2020-08-01 Germany   2020      8   10.0  1994-04-12       1459.90
2020-09-01 Germany   2020      9   10.0  1994-04-12       1459.90
2020-10-01 Germany   2020     10   10.0  1994-04-12       1459.90
2020-11-01 Germany   2020     11   10.0  1994-04-12       1459.90
2020-12-01 Germany   2020     12   10.0  1994-04-12       1459.90
2021-01-01 Germany   2021      1   10.0  1994-04-12       1459.90
2021-02-01 Germany   2021      2   10.0  1994-04-12       1459.90
2021-03-01 Germany   2021      3   10.0  1994-04-12       1459.90
2021-04-01 Germany   2021      4   10.0  1994-04-12       1459.90
2021-05-01 Germany   2021      5   10.0  1994-04-12       1459.90
2021-06-01 Germany   2021      6   10.0  1994-04-12       1459.90
2021-07-01 Germany   2021      7   10.0  1994-04-12       1459.90
2021-08-01 Germany   2021      8   10.0  1994-04-12       1459.90
2021-09-01 Germany   2021      9   10.0  1994-04-12       1459.90
2021-10-01 Germany   2021     10   10.0  1994-04-12       1459.90
2021-11-01 Germany   2021     11   10.0  1994-04-12       1459.90
2021-12-01 Germany   2021     12   10.0  1994-04-12       1459.90
2022-01-01 Germany   2022      1   10.0  1994-04-12       1459.90
2022-02-01 Germany   2022      2   10.0  1994-04-12       1459.90
2022-03-01 Germany   2022      3   10.0  1994-04-12       1459.90
2022-04-01 Germany   2022      4   10.0  1994-04-12       1459.90
2022-05-01 Germany   2022      5   10.0  1994-04-12       1459.90
2022-06-01 Germany   2022      6   10.0  1994-04-12       1459.90
2022-07-01 Germany   2022      7   10.0  1994-04-12       1459.90
2022-08-01 Germany   2022      8   10.0  1994-04-12       1459.90
2022-09-01 Germany   2022      9   10.0  1994-04-12       1459.90
2022-10-01 Germany   2022     10   10.0  1994-04-12       1459.90
2022-11-01 Germany   2022     11   10.0  1994-04-12       1459.90
2022-12-01 Germany   2022     12   10.0  1994-04-12       1459.90
2023-01-01 Germany   2023      1   10.0  1994-04-12       1459.90
2020-01-01 Zimbabwe  2020      1  108.0  2021-08-12       1171.88
2020-02-01 Zimbabwe  2020      2  108.0  2021-08-12       1171.88
2020-03-01 Zimbabwe  2020      3  108.0  2021-08-12       1171.88
2020-04-01 Zimbabwe  2020      4  108.0  2021-08-12       1171.88
2020-05-01 Zimbabwe  2020      5  108.0  2021-08-12       1171.88
2020-06-01 Zimbabwe  2020      6  108.0  2021-08-12       1171.88
2020-07-01 Zimbabwe  2020      7  108.0  2021-08-12       1171.88
2020-08-01 Zimbabwe  2020      8  108.0  2021-08-12       1171.88
2020-09-01 Zimbabwe  2020      9  108.0  2021-08-12       1171.88
2020-10-01 Zimbabwe  2020     10  108.0  2021-08-12       1171.88
2020-11-01 Zimbabwe  2020     11  108.0  2021-08-12       1171.88
2020-12-01 Zimbabwe  2020     12  108.0  2021-08-12       1171.88
2021-01-01 Zimbabwe  2021      1  108.0  2021-08-12       1171.88
2021-02-01 Zimbabwe  2021      2  108.0  2021-08-12       1171.88
2021-03-01 Zimbabwe  2021      3  108.0  2021-08-12       1171.88
2021-04-01 Zimbabwe  2021      4  108.0  2021-08-12       1171.88
2021-05-01 Zimbabwe  2021      5  108.0  2021-08-12       1171.88
2021-06-01 Zimbabwe  2021      6  108.0  2021-08-12       1171.88
2021-07-01 Zimbabwe  2021      7  108.0  2021-08-12       1171.88
2021-08-01 Zimbabwe  2021      8  108.0  2021-08-12       1171.88
2021-09-01 Zimbabwe  2021      9  108.0  2021-08-12       1171.88
2021-10-01 Zimbabwe  2021     10  108.0  2021-09-12       1171.88
2021-11-01 Zimbabwe  2021     11  108.0  2021-09-12       1171.88
2021-12-01 Zimbabwe  2021     12  108.0  2021-09-12       1171.88
2022-01-01 Zimbabwe  2022      1  108.0  2022-01-12       1120.00
2022-02-01 Zimbabwe  2022      2  108.0  2022-01-12       1120.00
2022-03-01 Zimbabwe  2022      3  108.0  2022-01-12       1120.00
2022-04-01 Zimbabwe  2022      4  108.0  2022-01-12       1120.00
2022-05-01 Zimbabwe  2022      5  108.0  2022-01-12       1120.00
2022-06-01 Zimbabwe  2022      6  108.0  2022-01-12       1120.00
2022-07-01 Zimbabwe  2022      7  108.0  2022-01-12       1120.00
2022-08-01 Zimbabwe  2022      8  108.0  2022-01-12       1120.00
2022-09-01 Zimbabwe  2022      9  108.0  2022-01-12       1120.00
2022-10-01 Zimbabwe  2022     10  108.0  2022-01-12       1120.00
2022-11-01 Zimbabwe  2022     11  108.0  2022-01-12       1120.00
2022-12-01 Zimbabwe  2022     12  108.0  2022-01-12       1120.00
2023-01-01 Zimbabwe  2023      1  108.0  2022-01-12       1120.00
```

Data I used as Input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'country_full': ['Zimbabwe','Zimbabwe','Zimbabwe','Germany','Germany','Germany'],
    'year': [2021, 2021, 2022, 2020, 2020, 2020],
    'month': [8, 10, 1, 1, 2, 4],
    'rank': [108, 108, 108, 10, 10, 10],
    'rank_date': ['2021-08-12','2021-09-12','2022-01-12','1994-01-12','1994-02-12','1994-04-12'],
    'total_points': [1171.88, 1171.88, 1120.0, 1171.88, 1327.8, 1459.9]
})
```